# Can i see both the web version and mobile version at one search for a single query?

Tags: google-search

When I am trying to search for my brand name i.e. ABC COMPANY, I can only see it with Mobile version that is m.ab.com. But I want to see both the versions at once like on search 1 it should be example.com and after it should be m.example.com/ Can you please suggest if it is possible?

Comment: check SEOfor site. sitemaps, register site, robots.txt... etc.
https://developers.google.com/search

Comment: Thanks for the respond! I am already doing SEO for my brand but don't know why the website not coming up on google. There is just a mobile version not the web version. Can you suggest?

Answer (score 0):

there is a lot.
**you must educate on SEO.**
but submit main site to google search, be sure you have a set of proper tags on homepage and robots.txt
register, request to crawl site
homepage will have a cross reference to mobile (as example)

it takes up to 24h+ to see changes.